# how to reorder the contingency table to form a confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, function, confusion-matrix

In terms of the application of clustering algorithm, after I got the contingency table of the counts at each combination of actual class and predicted class, for example,

```
  1  2  3
A 2  3  15
B 20 1  4
C 0  32 1
```

How could I write a function to get the confusion matrix that maximizes the diagonal by changing the order of columns? Thanks!

```
  1  2  3
A 15 2  3
B 4  20 1
C 1  0  32
```

Comment: just change the order of columns, i mean, c(2,20,0), c(3,1,32), c(15,4,1) would always be the three columns

Comment: can you please check whether the solution below is in the correct logic you imaginedd

Comment: This page describes an algorithm to calculate scores for the rows and columns that allow to reorder the contingency table so that high correspondences are placed on the diagonal. This works even for non-square tables: http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/lectures/day13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `max.col` to get the column index of the max value per row, and use that for rearranging the columns

```
m2 <- m1[,max.col(m1, 'first')]
colnames(m2) <- seq_len(ncol(m2))
m2
#   1  2  3
#A 15  2  3
#B  4 20  1
#C  1  0 32
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(2L, 20L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 32L, 15L, 4L, 1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
  3L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("1", "2", "3")))
```

Comment: I think this does not work as a column might contain the maximum value for multiple rows.

Comment: @moi `max.col` get the column index of max value per row.  If there are multiple max per row, `first` selects only the first column index where it occurs